# html5 make a phonecall in ios

Tags: javascript, ios, html

I make a website which can input a telephone number and click a button can make a phonecall with this number. As you do that, it will jump to a telephone app to call someone that you just inputed  number(this maybe the browser s work). When hang up the phone, it will jump back to the website.

Here is the question, when come back to the website, how can I know about had hanged up the phone and to display information in the website? Can I get the message use with JS? or it have some event in ios? thank you!

```
function callto(){
    var number = document.getElementById("telnumber").value;
    if( number == "" )
    {
         number = "xxxx";
         document.getElementById("telnumber").value = "xxxx";
    }
    window.location.href = "tel:" + number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, this information is not available. Not even in the native iOS SDK.